# To find the new weights of an error function by minimizing it

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, machine-learning, error-function

My task is to find the closed form solution $ \boldsymbol w^* $ that minimizes E(W) and hence find $y(x, \boldsymbol w^*)$

Consider the following error function

$E(\boldsymbol w) =  \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N {(y(x_n,\boldsymbol w)−t_n)^2} $

where w is a vector of weights; $x_n$ and $t_n$ come from two vectors of length N; and y is a polynomial:

y(x,w) = $ \sum\limits_{j=0}^M {w_jx^j} $

My task is to find the closed form solution $ \boldsymbol w^* $ to minimize E(W) and hence find $y(x, \boldsymbol w^*)$

So, I did
$\frac{\partial E(w)}{\partial w}$ = 0 and I obtained :

$ \sum\limits_{j=0}^M A_{ij} w_j = T_i$

where, $A_{ij} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n)^{i+j}$
and $T_i = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n)^i t_n $

But I'm not really sure how to solve for $w$ and find $y(x, \boldsymbol w^*)$

Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the powers of $x$ into a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

$$\eqalign{
 V_{ij} &= (x_i)^{\,j} \cr
 y(x_n,w) &= \sum_{j=0}^M w_jV_{nj} \cr
}$$
The last equation has a very simple form in matrix notation 
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Vw\cr
}$$
Utilizing the trace/Frobenius product,
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ 
allows the error function to be written in a form which makes the differential and gradient easy to calculate.
$$\eqalign{
E &= \frac{1}{2}\,(y-t):(y-t) \cr
dE &= (y-t):dy = (y-t):V\,dw = V^T(y-t):dw \cr
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w} &= V^T(y-t) = V^T(Vw-t) \cr
}$$
Now set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
V^TVw &= V^Tt \cr
w^* &= (V^TV)^{-1}V^Tt \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. In the final equation that you have given, I notice that t and w are not capitalized. That means t and w are not matrices? How come?

Comment: @Justin In the problem statement, you said that $\{w,x,t\}$ are vectors. Why do you now think they ought to be matrices?